# 'Null'? Problems with assigning in a class

Tags: java

The problem is that I am getting an unexpected error from my movie reviewer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class deTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    aClass bClass=new aClass();

    System.out.print("What is the movie you want to review?... ");
    bClass.movies=kbScanner.nextLine();

    do{
        System.out.print("What would you give it out of 10?... ");
        bClass.ratings=kbScanner.nextInt();
        if (bClass.ratings>10){
            System.out.println("Sorry, your rating went over 10. Please try again...");
        }
        if (bClass.ratings<=10){
            System.out.println("You gave a rating of "+bClass.ratings+".");
        }
    }while (bClass.ratings>10);

    bClass.graderate(bClass.ratings, bClass.grade);
    System.out.println("This movie got a grade of "+bClass.grade);
    bClass.printInfo(bClass.movies, bClass.ratings, bClass.grade);

}
}
```

And here is the class:

```
public class aClass {
String movies;
int ratings;
String grade;

void graderate(int ratings,String grade){
    switch (ratings){
    case 1:
        grade=("C");
        break;
    case 2:
        grade=("C");
        break;
    case 3:
        grade=("C");
        break;
    case 4:
        grade=("B");
        break;
    case 5:
        grade=("B");
        break;
    case 6:
        grade=("B");
        break;
    case 7:
        grade=("A");
        break;
    case 8:
        grade=("A");
        break;
    case 9:
        grade=("A");
        break;
    case 10:
        grade=("A+");
        break;
    default:
        grade=("?");
    }


}
void printInfo(String movies,int ratings,String grade){
    System.out.println("The movie "+movies+" was given rating of "+ratings+" out of 10 and received a grade of "+ grade);
}
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
What is the movie you want to review?... Titanic
What would you give it out of 10?... 7
You gave a rating of 7.
This movie got a grade of null
The movie Titanic was given rating of 7 out of 10 and received a grade of null
```

Instead of giving me the Grade, which is a string, the console keeps placing null in the place of the Grade. This error was after I changed the bClass.grade from a char to String. When the bClass.grade was a char, I got:

```
What is the movie you want to review?... Real Steel
What would you give it out of 10?... 10
You gave a rating of 10.
This movie got a grade of 
The movie Titanic was given rating of 10 out of 10 and received a grade of
```

With nothing in the place of the grade.So, what am I doing wrong with my movie reviewer?

Comment: `grade` is a local variable in the scope of your method `graderate`, you don't modify the field in your class.

Comment: I wouldn't use a switch, I would use a Map, or simple if tests for range.

Comment: Yep, contrary to your belief, graderate doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: Sorry guys, did not know that you could only have one correct answer XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `grade` in `graderate(...)` is hiding the `grade` instance of the class `aClass`, so what you are modifying in the `switch` is the local variable `grade`(parameter) , not the field. It's not necessary to pass it since `grade` is a field of the class:

```
void graderate(int ratings)
{
    switch (ratings)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        grade = ("C");
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        grade = ("B");
        break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        grade = ("A");
        break;
    case 10:
        grade = ("A+");
        break;
    default:
        grade = ("?");
    }
}
```

And call it in your `main` method as:

```
bClass.graderate(bClass.ratings);
```

**Note** that you can simplify your `switch` by "grouping cases", so you don't repeat code (look modifications above, it's straightforward).

Comment: So, what you are saying that if I don't put grade as a local variable and skip it, I would be able to modify my aClass's grade?

Comment: Of couse, because `gradeRate` method is in the `aClass` grade.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `graderate(int ratings,String grade)` of class aClass, the variable `grade` is not the aClass instance's attribute grade but the parameter grade. If you wanna change the attribute grade's value, write `this.grade` instead of `grade`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what this.grade does to my class's variables?

Comment: `this` is just a reference to an instance of the class. Speficying `this.grade` says that you want to refer to the **field** `grade`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
bClass.graderate(bClass.ratings, bClass.grade);
```

By

```
bClass.graderate(bClass.ratings);//, bClass.grade  //No need to pass this
```

And

```
void graderate(int ratings,String grade){
```

By

```
void graderate(int ratings){
```

OUTPUT:

```
What is the movie you want to review?... titanic
What would you give it out of 10?... 7
You gave a rating of 7.
This movie got a grade of A
The movie titanic was given rating of 7 out of 10 and received a grade of A
```